# Connect two SPI RFID readers in the Raspberry Pi B +

Tags: spi, rfid

I followed this tutorial to connect one RC522 RFID reader in a Raspberry Pi.

http://www.nikolaus-lueneburg.de/2014/06/rfid-rc522-modul-mit-spi-schnittstelle/

I'm able to connect it to work with slave 1, using the CE0 pin (P24 - GPIO8) on Raspbberry 1 B+.

I would like to connect two equal RC522 RFID readers in the Raspberry Pi. But with the code provided in the tutorial I wasn't able to connect the reader as Slave 2 (CE1, in pin P26). And consequently, I couldn't connect both at the same time.

Details: The code from the tutorial we are using is here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/rpi-rc522/source/default/source

The modifications we tried is in the function on the file `main.c`

```
uint8_t HW_init(uint32_t spi_speed, uint8_t gpio) {
uint16_t sp;

sp=(uint16_t)(250000L/spi_speed);
if (!bcm2835_init()) {
    syslog(LOG_DAEMON|LOG_ERR,"Can't init bcm2835!\n");
    return 1;
}
if (gpio<28) {
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(gpio, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_write(gpio, LOW);
}

bcm2835_spi_begin();
bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);      // The default
bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);                   // The default
bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(sp); // The default
bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);                      // The default
bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);      // the default
return 0;
}
```

We tried to change the 2 occurrences of `BCM2835_SPI_CS0` to `BCM2835_SPI_CS1`, but it don't detect any card in this way, changing the CS pin from p24 to p26). The `gpio` parameter is defined in a config file, with default value to 18, and changing it don't seems to affect it.

Comment: What Pi is it, 2 or 3? Anyway, both have 2 SPI, just use them. Where is your code?

Comment: my code is https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/rpi-rc522/source-archive.zip

PI B+ first version with 40 GPIO