# How to connect Multiple RFID Readers to a Single Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, rfid

I would like to interface multiple RFID Readers to a single Raspberry Pi. Any option can be chosen either wired or wirelessly.

Comment: those are two good options

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/51543/5538